# I cannot recognise this kana

Tags: hiragana

[image]

Hello. I've circled characters I cannot recognise. The top one looks like を but there is an actual をnext to it and it looks different. Why? The middle one is ゆ in my opinion. But I'm not sure about that. Why does it look different to the usual ゆ? And according to my research the bottom one is ず. But again I have to ask why is there another ずand it doesn't look like that? Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Welcome to [japanese.se]! Could you mention the source for the image to make this question more improved?

Answer (score 32):

They're [hentaigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hentaigana), forms which were used before the 1900 script reform.
From top to bottom: な、ゆ、ず.

> [image: list of alternative forms of kana]
>
> <sup>[Source](http://users.monash.edu/%7Ejwb/rose.jpg)</sup>